# Android studio 2.3: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.actions.NewKotlinActivityAction

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, android-studio-2.3

I have just updated Android studio **2.2.2** to **2.3** from the canary channel. After downloading completed and applying path file, the android studio is restarting.
But after restarting android studio I am getting below error with dialog:

> Cannot load project:
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException:
>   com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Could not initialize class
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.actions.NewKotlinActivityAction [Plugin:
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin]

See below screenshot for to get more idea:

[image: android studio kotline error 1]

After closing dialog by ok and restarting android studio, also I can't able to open my project or creating new project.

[image: android studio kotline error 2]

Does anyone is facing same issue after updating android studio?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Disable the Kotlin plugin and restart Android Studio. I had the same error even after I updated the plugin. So disabling seems to be the solution for now -- unless you're using Kotlin, I guess.

The Kotlin team confirmed a fix is in the works via twitter: https://twitter.com/kotlin/status/797111726516879360

Comment: Yes. I just disable kotlin plugin from **Settings -> Plugins -> Kotlin** and restarting android studio. it is worked for me.

Comment: Also reported issue for the same : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227576

Comment: The same bug continues to exist at the end of 2017.... Why do they say they SUPPORT Kotlin?

Answer (score 9):

The issue is fixed in Kotlin plugin version 1.0.5-2.

Comment: Thanks @yole. I just installed the new version of kotlin and it's working fine.

Comment: Unfortunately the same issue exist in 1.1.60 and Studio3.0-1

Comment: @Sniper Yes, I have IntelliJ 17.1 and Kotlin 1.1.1. Just now in 12.2017 I have installed every last version... And the same problem. It seems, IJ becomes even more unstable that Eclipse.

Answer (score 9):

Issue is fixed in new update of Kotlin, you can update your plugin from

**Configuration>Plugin>Install JetBrains Plugin>Select "Kotlin" from List and hit "Update" from right menu**

[image]

Comment: I had to uninstall and install again Kotlin plugin to make it work.

Comment: yes that is another choice.. but you can just disable it for a while or you can just update it.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Updating the 'ext.kotlin_version' on root build.gradle to the latest fixed the issue for me. Use this link to find the [latest kotlin version](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html).

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me just today after updating my Kotlin's plug-in verison from 1.1.51 to 1.1.60. I had to uninstall this version from *Settings* > *Pluings* in Android Studio and install the previous one, which can be downloaded from [JetBrains plug-ins repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin).

If you're using Android Studio 3.0, you don't need to install the previous version of the plug-in again since version 1.1.51 is built-in in Android Studio.